# Tem alguma forma de adicionar "tooltip" do Bootstrap a força?

Tags: html, bootstrap-3, tooltip

Eu tenho um botão no meu site ***Wordpress***, ou seja dentro da postagem!

Botão:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" id="butdedownlaodnovo" 
data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" role="button" 
target="_blank" aria-pressed="true" data-original-title="Comente, 
agradeça!"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> BAIXAR 
AGORA</a>
```

mas tenho umas postagens que não coloquei o : `data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" data-original-title="Comente, agradeça!"`

Tem como fazer o javascript adicionar isso automaticamente pelo tema, ou outro tipo ? sem eu precisar editar todas as postagens...

Comment: Tem, mas qual o critério para definir se o link terá ou não o tooltip?

Comment: Quero que todos os links com o id `butdedownlaodnovo` tenha o tooltip que eu definir!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode adicionar os atributos de forma dinâmica com (conforme informado no chat):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("a", ".novolinkdedownload").attr({
      "data-original-title": "Comente, agradeça!",
      "data-toggle": "tooltip",
      "data-placement": "top"
   });
});
```

Comment: Ajudou muito, obrigado!