# Como mudar o conteúdo de uma DIV se caso estiver usando adblock

Tags: php, javascript, html

Eai pessoal, no meu site tem um botão dentro de uma div:

```
<div class="novolinkdedownload">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" id="butdedownlaodnovo">BAIXAR AGORA</a>
</div>
```

tem alguma forma de se o usuário estiver usando o famoso adblock sumir a *DIV* original e aparecer outra que eu possa criar com uma mensagem, ou coisa do tipo, ou seja apareceu aparece um mensagem no lugar do botão pedindo pra desativar e recarregar a pagina?

> OBSERVAÇÃO

Ja tentei as opções abaixo eu não consigo.

LINK: [Anti-adblock que substitui div](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293972/anti-adblock-que-substitui-div) e [Detectar AdBlock e exibir uma mensagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/87961/detectar-adblock-e-exibir-uma-mensagem/87992#87992)

Comment: Aqui vc consegue fácil https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/289510/8063

Comment: Se tiver dúvidas pode chamar. :)

Comment: Vi aqui, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer para um botão.

Comment: Vc quer substituir o botão por um texto?

Comment: Eu queria substituir o texto do botão, e remover o link de download que esta nele se caso tiver com adoblock ativado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o FuckAdblock e usar a função `adBlockDetected()` para fazer o que deseja.

Abaixo um código para remover o link da `div` caso o seja detectado algum adblock ativo e substituir com um texto:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){

   function adBlockDetected() {
      document.body.querySelector(".novolinkdedownload").innerHTML = "Desative o adblock e recarregue a página!"
   }

   if(typeof fuckAdBlock !== 'undefined' || typeof FuckAdBlock !== 'undefined') { 
      adBlockDetected(); 
   } else { 

      var importFAB = document.createElement('script'); 
      importFAB.onload = function() { 
         fuckAdBlock.onDetected(adBlockDetected);
      }
      importFAB.onerror = function() { 
         adBlockDetected(); 
      }
      importFAB.src = 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fuckadblock/3.2.1/fuckadblock.min.js'; 
      document.head.appendChild(importFAB); 
   }
});
```

Comment: Funcionou 100%, mas uma pergunta, tem como na hora que ele remover o link, adicionar um ID pra eu poder personalizar a div ? e não usar o css do original.

Comment: Sim, vc pode fazer o que quiser dentro da função, modificar o que quiser. Vou abrir um chat para que vc me explique melhor.

Comment: Ou melhor, vai falando aqui.

Comment: Dentro de "Desative o adblock e recarregue a página!" eu posso criar um DIV nova ? e editar ela depois por css ?

Comment: Pode fazer oq  quiser... BAsta inserir o que quiser na div `.novolinkdedownload`....

Comment: Obrigado;) me ajudou muito!

Comment: è só colocar no innerHTML o que quiser

Comment: Valeu, muito obrigado mesmo. Eu tenho outra pergunta aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/293904/tem-alguma-forma-de-adicionar-tooltip-do-bootstrap-a-for%C3%A7a , consegue responder pra min ?

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76582/discussion-between-dvd-and-matheus-vitor).